# Which compiler options to use with gfortran?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am using Fortran 90 with the gfortran compiler. It's my first experience with a compiled language. Why not just use all of the compiler options when compiling? Would it slow down running the executable? Which compiler options do you recommend? Also, how does gfortran compare to other compilers for Fortran 90? What is important to know about it?

Answer (score 2):

For developing and debugging: `-Og -g -Wall -pedantic -fcheck=all`

For maximum performance once you have a functioning program, benchmark and test, but as a starting point look in the manual what `-O2`, `-O3`, `-Ofast`, `-ffast-math`, `-funroll-loops`, `-march=native` do. Be particularly careful wrt `-Ofast` and `-ffast-math`.

Comment: I would strongly  recommend -std=f2008 always, and for debugging -finit-real=snan . There are others, but it's late and I need to look them up, I may come back